# Regex String To Skip Text - Java

Tags: java, regex

For an assignment I'm trying to parse some HTML using Regex, and having trouble getting the expression exactly right. I'm looking to catch a group for city, route URL, and route number. I have a string that gets me the city, and another that gets me the route URL & route number, but I haven't been able to get them to work together and skip the text between the tags where the three desired variables are located. Here's an example of the site HTML I'm parsing:

```
                <hr id="brier" />
                <h3>Brier</h3>
                    <div class="row Community">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 text-nowrap">
                            <strong><a href="/schedules/route/111">111</a></strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">Brier to Mountlake Terrace</div>
                    </div>
                <hr id="darrington" />
                <h3>Darrington</h3>
                    <div class="row Community">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 text-nowrap">
                            <strong><a href="/schedules/route/230">230</a></strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">Darrington to Smokey Point</div>
                    </div>
                <hr id="edmonds" />
```

My first expression captures the city name (Brier) in the H3 tags:  `("<h3>(.*?)</h3>")`

My second captures all of the route URLs and numbers after the href:`" <strong><a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</a>"`

I tried just skipping everything between them:  `(<h3>(.*?)</h3>.*?<strong><a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</a>)` 
but it didnt work for me. The ultimate goal is to load them into a Map using a while loop (Map<city, LinkedHashMap<routeNUM, routeURL>>, so I think I'll also need something at the end of the expression to stop it from loading all values to every city.

Any ideas on how I can achieve all of this in a single expression? Posting my actual code excerpt below as well for reference:

```
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(routesURL.getInputStream()));
        Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> outerMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String,String>>();
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        //Read site lines and add to String
        while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
            
            text+= inputLine + "\n";
        }
        Pattern Pattern = Pattern.compile("<h3>(.*?)</h3>.*?<strong><a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</a>");
        Matcher Matcher = routePattern.matcher(text);
        while (Matcher.find()) {
            String city = Matcher.group(1);
            String routeURL = Matcher.group(1);
            String routeNum = Matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println(routeNum + " " + fullURL);
            //Add URL and routeNum to innerMap
            outerMap.put(city, createInnerMap(routeNum, fullURL));
            System.out.println(outerMap);
            }
        }
```

I'm open to keeping it in two expressions, but when I did the result was that it added every route under the first city as the key, and stopped instead of attributing only the correct routes to each city and then looping again and adding the next city as the next key in the outerMap. Here is a sample of the code with two matchers:

```
        Pattern routePattern = Pattern.compile("<strong><a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</a>");
        Matcher routeMatcher = routePattern.matcher(text);
        Pattern cityPattern = Pattern.compile("<h3>(.*?)</h3>");
        Matcher cityMatcher = cityPattern.matcher(text);
        while (cityMatcher.find()) {
            String city = cityMatcher.group(1);
            while (routeMatcher.find()) {
                String routeURL = routeMatcher.group(1);
                String routeNum = routeMatcher.group(2);
                //Builds full route URL
                String fullURL;
                fullURL = URLtruncate + routeURL;
                System.out.println(routeNum + " " + fullURL);
                //Add URL and routeNum to innerMap
                outerMap.put(city, createInnerMap(routeNum, fullURL));
                System.out.println(outerMap);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do it as a single expression. I wouldn’t. It creates a coupling between irrelevant parsing operations. Keep things simple by keeping things separate.

Comment: You're probably right, but I encountered a problem when I did that (I edited the post to include the code when I used two matchers above) which resulted in the Map being inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(routesURL.getInputStream()));
List<String> lines = input.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> outerMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String,String>>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

Pattern Pattern1 = Pattern.compile("<h3>(.*?)</h3>");
Pattern Pattern2 = Pattern.compile("<strong><a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</a></strong>");

for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
    Matcher Matcher = Pattern1.matcher(lines.get(i));
    if(Matcher.find()){
        String city = Matcher.group(1);
        Matcher = Pattern2.matcher(lines.get(i + 3));
        Matcher.find();
        String routeURL = Matcher.group(1);
        String routeNum = Matcher.group(2);
        String fullURL = "full" + routeURL;
        System.out.println(routeNum + " " + fullURL);
        //Add URL and routeNum to innerMap
        outerMap.put(city, createInnerMap(routeNum, fullURL));
        System.out.println(outerMap);
        i=i+4;
    }
}
```